# Is it true that the eight richest men have more wealth than the bottom 50% of world population?

Tags: debt, inequality

This statistic from Oxfam, an anti-poverty consortium, has been reported in prominent media outlets ([example](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/16/world/eight-richest-wealth-oxfam.html)). Other articles dispute this statistic as misleading due to flimsy assumptions about debt ([example](http://fusion.net/story/380433/oxfams-davos-wealth-inequality-wrong-misleading/))

Comment: What part of the fusion.net article's explanation is unclear?

Comment: Nothing is unclear, but maybe the fusion.net article is also misleading, and there's a convincing counterargument that I can't think of.

Comment: Related: http://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/12890/what-was-the-worlds-wealth-in-2015